# Disable blocking in phpseclib/SSH2?

Tags: stream, blocking, phpseclib

I'm running some commands on multiple servers and I want them to all run concurrently,

```
foreach($clust['hosts'] as $hostStr) {
    list($host, $port) = Str::rsplit($hostStr,':',2,22);

    $ssh = new \Net_SSH2($host, $port);

    if(!$ssh->login($username,$key)) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not connect to $username@$host:$port");
    }

    $connections[] = $ssh;

}

foreach($connections as $i=>$ssh) {
    $ssh->exec('cd /path/to/my/project && hg up', function($str) {
        echo $str;
    });
    echo "right after ls $i\n";
}
```

But this always runs sequentially. Can I tell `Net_SSH2` to be non-blocking?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could probably do is to use `$ssh->setTimeout(1)` or `$ssh->setTimeout(0.5)` or something.

You could also probably do `$ssh->write(...)` and just not do `$ssh->read()`.

Comment: Using `setTimeout` won't abort the command, it will just stop waiting for a response?

Comment: Yup - I believe that's correct! You should be able to verify by doing ps aux | grep command in a separate ssh window.